# fscanf in C - commas, new lines, and %*c

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to use fscanf() to read a file which is made up of a list of doubles separated by commas and new lines. The file looks something like this

```
    3.000000,1.000000,1180.000000,1955.000000,221900.000000
    3.000000,2.250000,2570.000000,1951.000000,538000.000000
    2.000000,1.000000,770.000000,1933.000000,180000.000000
    4.000000,3.000000,1960.000000,1965.000000,604000.000000
    3.000000,2.000000,1680.000000,1987.000000,510000.000000
```

Each line will have the same amount of doubles as the others but the file will have a random amount of lines

What I am using right now to scan the file is

```
    while((fscanf(train, "%lf %*c", &k)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%lf ", k);
    }
```

Using this I get

```
    3.000000 1.000000 1180.000000 1955.000000 221900.000000
    0.000000 2.250000 2570.000000 1951.000000 538000.000000
    0.000000 1.000000 770.000000 1933.000000 180000.000000
    0.000000 3.000000 1960.000000 1965.000000 604000.000000
    0.000000 2.000000 1680.000000 1987.000000 510000.000000
```

The problem with this is that a the beginning of each new line, the %*c skips the first part of the double, and prints 0.000000. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Try `while((fscanf(train, "%lf ,", &k)) == 1)`

Comment: Thanks that worked, but just for future reference, is there any way to make it so that it reads the %*c until it gets to the end of the line then starts again?

Comment: By`%*c` there is no comma at the end of the line, so the first nonblank character on the next line will be skipped. So use `%lf%*c` instead of `%lf %*c` (When there is no gap as in the example)

Comment: @PaulKim "to make it so that it reads the %*c until it gets to the end of the line then starts again" --> various brittle solutions.  Best is to read the _line_ with `fgets()` and then parse.

Answer (score 1):

When `fscanf(train, "%lf %*c", &k)` is reading the last number, the whitespace character swallows the newline, and the `%*c` swallows the first digit of the next number. So, the subsequent application of the `fscanf` call will only see `.000000` when it tries to read the first number of the next line.

Since there isn't actually any whitespace between the numbers and commas, just get rid of it in your format string.

```
while((fscanf(train, "%lf%*c", &k)) != EOF)
```

While `fscanf` will return `EOF` when it encounters the end of file, it will otherwise return the number of successful elements scanned into your arguments. Since you pass in 1, you expect to get 1 in return. On bad input, `fscanf` report 0 arguments saved in your case. However, the bad data is left in the input buffer, so a subsequent call will fail in the same way. So, the `EOF` check would result in an infinite loop. You can change your code to check if the scan succeeded. (This point was noted in comments by [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux).)

```
while((fscanf(train, "%lf%*c", &k)) == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [fgets](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) and then parse the line:

```
double d;
char *lineBuf = malloc(MAX_LINE + 1); // Or size more appropriately to your needs.

while (fgets(lineBuf, MAX_LINE + 1, inputFile) == lineBuf)
{
    d = atolf(lineBuf); // Stops at first comma or whitespace.
    printf("%lf", d);
}
```

If you're interested in more than one field, use [strtok](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) to break out the fields.